# Edit Text without Autocorrect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want an EditText without the autocorrection.
I have set the textNoSuggestions inputType, as shown:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtTarga"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Targa"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textCapCharacters" >
```

The capitalize flag works, but it is still autocorrecting.

How can I disable it?

Comment: `inputType` is a request. The developers of input method editors may or may not honor all of those requests. Whether or not any given request will be honored will depend on the input method editor, and different devices will have different editors.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

inputType textVisiblePassword will do the trick (most of the times, because as Commonsware pointed out, it stays a request and you'll might find yourself finding devices where it works, and devices where it doesn't work)

Comment: android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword". This seems to work on Samsung Galaxy S2 running 4.0.4

Answer (score 9):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

according to [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/143278), inputType attribute may or may not be supported by some devices .

However, this seems to work more often

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try by code, something like this:

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTarga);
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="password"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
```

In java source code

```
    // casting done from EditText to TextView

    TextView mPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
```

> No idea why is this. But works fine.

Comment: With `android:inputType="textPassword"` you convert all the text in `*****`, as when you type a password. Same behaviour to you or different? (I didn't cast it)

Comment: Yes its gets showed as ***** ,but  @Error404 problem is for password fields auto suggestions list get populated which needs to suppressed.

Comment: But if you add `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` it doesn't give to you any suggestion. At least for me.

Comment: Across devices  behaviour is different. Some devices turns up to suggestions for `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"  `. So the alternate workaround is provided. If can test on `Samsung Galaxy S4`. Use my above with ` class casting to TextView` and no `class casting using as it as EdittextView `

Answer (score 0):

`textNoSuggestions` does not work in every keyboard. The accepted answer `inputType="textVisiblePassword"` works but it removes emoji's from most keyboards.

I found that setting `inputType="textUri"` works and keeps the ability to add emojis.