# android - avoid text to be underlined in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

When I write a text in an EditText it gets underline until I hit the space key. I've tried:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

But it's not helping

Comment: AFAIK, that's up to the input method editor (a.k.a., soft keyboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the default 'underlining' of EditText, try setting its background to transparent.

Comment: No, i appears every time a type a new word and it underline that word

Comment: @MarianoPelizzari Have you tried different languages? Also specifying minimum target API version in the question would be helpful.

Comment: I cannot specify an api lesser than 16 and I've tried in a different device, with Lollipop, and is not happening. Perhaps is the android version of the device where it's happening (samsung and 4.3)

Comment: @MarianoPelizzari Have a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870111/edit-text-without-autocorrect

Answer (score 0):

try to add following lines in java code-

```
mEditText.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

If you need to support API 4 and below, use `android:inputType="textFilter"`